# Force User to Provide One of Two Answers?

Tags: java

So, in Java, I want the user to provide either Y or N to my prompt. Lets say (dream sequence begins with swirly sounds) I am currently using this code:

```
String output = "";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.println("[P]ast or [F]uture?");

    String input = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    if (input.equals("p") || input.equals("f")){
        output = input;
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please provide a valid answer.");
    }
}
```

There has got to be a more efficient way of doing this. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Programming is all about abstraction. Write this code once; a function that takes a prompt string like that and returns the entered value, and hide all the complexity and validation and mess within the function. Later, you can call a super-clean looking `prompt("[P]ast or [F]uture?")` method!

Comment: Other than the fact that your program will never end, I don't see anything wrong with the way you have it now.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it's a request for general improvements to make to working code. You might have better luck on [CodeReview.SE], but be sure to read their help center before you post it there.

Comment: You mean something like: `prompt("[P]ast or [F]uture", new Array{'p', 'f'})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can force the user to type in something. You'll have to sanitize the data and throw an error at the user when he types in something wrong, much like your code is doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GUI library such as Swing or JavaFX and only allow the allowable input. For instance if this were Swing and the user were entering input into a JTextField, you could add a DocumentFilter to the JTextField's document, preventing the user from entering anything but 'y' or 'n'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *hasNext(String pattern)* to validate that the next token consists of your desired pattern?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext_pattern.htm

```
while (!sc.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        sc.next();
    }
```